# Can we give a precise definition to say "$b$ is $m$- times greater than $a$?"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, number-comparison

Let $a,b\in R$ and $a<b.$ Can we give a precise definition to say "$b$ is $m$- times greater than $a$?" in general. For the positive $0<a<b$ it is clear. "We say that $b$ is $m$-times greater than $a$ if $\frac{b}{a}=m.$" How about if both are negative or one negative the other one is positive?

Comment: This means $b = ma$.

Comment: @Toby Mak. I don't think so

Comment: I would agree with Toby. What makes you disagree, MIYY? Do you have a particular example for this?

Comment: @Matti P. Let's take $a=-8$ and $b=-2$ try to write $b$ is 4 time bigger than $a$

Comment: Good point, actually. It's so simple to accidentally assume that variables are positive ...

Comment: @MIYY: Please include specific concerns (eg, negatives) as part of the question itself, so that people don't waste time giving responses you're prepared to rebut. (I'd thought your concern might relate to how "$b$ is $100\%$ bigger than $a$" means $b=a+a=2a=a\cdot 200\%$, yet some people (wrongly) say "$a$ increased by $300\%$" to mean $a\to a\cdot 300\%$.) ... In any case, common language is ambiguous, so formal translation can depend upon context. It might be good to ask how best to *informally* translate $b=ma$, since "$m$-times bigger" may not always *sound* right (eg, with negatives).

Comment: @Blue My concern is the following. Two different negative numbers are given  $a<b<0$ how to determine that $b$ is $m$-times bigger than $a$? We are not going to use percentages. How about if $a<0<b$?

Comment: Generally, for any $a<b$ can we give a precise definition to say   "$b$ is $m$ times bigger than $a$"?

Comment: @MIYY: Put your concerns and clarifications into the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked (and can be hidden).

Comment: It's in natural language, so the possibility of misinterpretation is open. It sounds like you could draw a distinction between "bigger" talking about magnitude and "greater" talking about number line ordering. But it would be something more likely to be apparent from context rather than a "rule" of what the words mean.

Comment: You seem to be hanging-up on the semantics of treating "bigger than" as a synonym for "greater than"; the resolution might be: *Don't do that.* ... Personally, I try to use *bigger/smaller than* in an "absolute (value)" sense, as they connote comparison in *size*; whereas *greater/less than* are agreed-upon conventions for *order*. Thus, I'd say $-8$ is "less than", yet "bigger than", $-2$. Not everyone would agree with my terminological choices here, but at least they avoid the semantic issue. ... Even so, I'm not sure I'd say "$-8$ is $4$-times bigger than $-2$" out loud; it sounds weird. :)

Comment: Is "$b$ is $m$ times $a$" not satisfactory?

Comment: @MIYY If $b$ is $m$ times greater than $a$, then $b > a$. If both $a$ and $b$ are less than zero, then that will not be true as $-b < -a$. As Matti P. and Blue pointed out, you can think in terms of _absolute values_.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "b is m times **as large as** a" means that b= ma but that "b is m times **larger** than a" means that b= a+ ma= (m+1)a.

Comment: The second variant is very original.